# set negative number to zero Powershell

Tags: powershell

With Powershell, is there a function to set a negative number to zero?

Or is this it?

```
If ($num -lt 0) {$num = 0}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you're looking for a more *concise* way:

```
$num = [math]::max(0, $num)
```

A [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) alternative, using the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false):

```
$num = $num -lt 0 ? 0 : $num
```